# Capturing image with WDS is stuck on 'Capturing Windows Image Metadata'

Tags: wds

I'm trying to capture a rather large (100gigs) windows xp partition to a WIM file on an attached USB hard drive.  Under 'Task Progress' it's saying 'Capturing Windows image Metadata', which is where it has been for a while (like 1.5 hours) - the blue bar is at the end of the screen, i.e. 100%

I can move the windows around the screen so I suspect that the operation hasn't crashed yet but does this part of the process take a long time?  I have only ever captured a 3gig partition before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The process recently finished after maybe 2 hours.  The Capturing Windows Image Metadata must take longer due to the size of the partition it's capturing...

Answer (score 0):

When capturing a Windows 10 image to WDS, I had a similar issue:
The "Windows Deployment Services Image Capturing Wizard" was stuck at 50% / "Capturing Windows image metadata...".

For me waiting did not resolve the issue (it was still stuck in the next morning).
As it turned out, the capturing of the WIM file was apparently done (contrary to what the status text implies) but there might have been an issue with the upload to the WDS server.
My solution was the following:

- Next to the stuck wizard, launch a command prompt via **Shift+F10**
- Locate the WIM file, e.g. via `dir D:`
- Connect to a network share via `net use \\myShare /user:user pw`
- Copy the WIM file to the share via `xcopy d:\my.wim \\myShare`
- After the WIM file was copied to the WDS server, I was able to manually add the install image there via **Add Install Image...**